# Saving numpy 32int into multi layer tiff

Tags: python, numpy, tiff

I am working with scientific images, where something is called "Line" have a sequence of (n) grayscale images.
What I do is I color the images of each line with a specific color, and then I merge the corresponding image of each line together (i.e. I merge image_0 of each line into one image, and then image_1 of each line into one and so on).
The result is a colored merged sequence of (n) images.

My goal now is to save this sequence into one tiff file, which I couldn't so far.

```
def load_image(infilename):
    img = Image.open(infilename)
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray(img, dtype="int32")
    return data

def merge_lines_images(lines, colors):
    rotations_count = len(lines[0])
    layers = []
    for rotation in range(0, rotations_count):
        images_to_merge = []
        for line in lines:
            img = load_image(line[rotation])
            images_to_merge.append(img)

        colored_images = []
        for img_index, img in enumerate(images_to_merge):
            color = colors[img_index]

            r = img * color[0] / 255

            g = img * color[1] / 255

            b = img * color[2] / 255

            rgb = np.dstack((r,g,b))
            colored_images.append(rgb)

        merged_image = np.zeros(colored_images[0].shape)

        for img in colored_images:
            merged_image += img

        clipped = np.clip(merged_image, 0, 255, out=merged_image)

        layers.append(clipped)
```

How to save the "layers" array into one multi-layer tiff file?

Thank you very much

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `32int`. Try [tifffile](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html): `with tifffile.TiffWriter('layers.tif') as tif:for image in layers:tif.save(image.astype('uint8'), photometric='rgb')`

Comment: Yea it worked!! Thank you very very much :D